# Set of structures being marked as undefined in 32 bit build of Judy Arrays but not 64 bit?

Tags: c, 32bit-64bit, judy-array

I am trying to test out using Judy Arrays. I wrote a short program that essentially tests simply inserting and retrieving strings from a Judy Array, using the JSLI and JSLG functions. The program inserts a list of strings, then finds them and prints out the strings in the order they were inserted and retrieved. I tried to compile with GCC.

When I used the 64 build of Judy (followed instructions as specified in the INSTALL file), the program worked fine. When I used the 32 bit version, my program would not compile, throwing a list of errors, about structures being undefined, as show below. What could be causing such an error?

Full Error Message:

```
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLNext.c:445: undefined reference to `j__L_LeafWOffset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLNext.c:462: undefined reference to `j__L_LeafWOffset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLNext.c:1610: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf1Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLNext.c:1618: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf2Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLNext.c:866: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf4Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLNext.c:773: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf3Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLNext.c:873: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf5Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLNext.c:881: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf6Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLNext.c:889: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf7Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLNext.c:1671: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf7Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLNext.c:1662: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf6Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLNext.c:1653: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf5Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLNext.c:1645: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf4Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLNext.c:1637: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf3Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLNext.c:851: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf2Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLNext.c:844: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf1Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLNext.c:858: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf3Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLPrev.c:445: undefined reference to `j__L_LeafWOffset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLPrev.c:462: undefined reference to `j__L_LeafWOffset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLPrev.c:1610: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf1Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLPrev.c:1618: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf2Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLPrev.c:775: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf4Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLPrev.c:773: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf3Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLPrev.c:777: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf6Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLPrev.c:776: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf5Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLPrev.c:778: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf7Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLPrev.c:1671: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf7Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLPrev.c:1662: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf6Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLPrev.c:1653: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf5Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLPrev.c:1645: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf4Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLPrev.c:1637: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf3Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLPrev.c:772: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf2Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLPrev.c:770: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf1Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLPrev.c:873: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf5Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLPrev.c:866: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf4Offset'
/dv/scratch/users/testacct/judy_take_two/src/JudyL/JudyLPrev.c:851: undefined reference to `j__L_Leaf2Offset'
```

Comment: The library header was not available? Strangely, the errors are not in line order.